# Attach the text view to your fragment class

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    var amount        : Long = edt_amount_layout_22.text.toString().toLong()
    var interest_rate : Long = edt_Interest_rate_layout_22.text.toString().toLong()
    var month         : Long = edt_month_layout_22.text.toString().toLong()         * 30
    
    val result        : Double = (amount*month*interest_rate)/36500.0
    
    view.findViewById<MaterialTextView>(R.id.edt_Installment_layout_22).text= result.toString()
```

**how to Attach the text view to your fragment class ?**

Comment: Hello, I was wondering what "Attach the text view to your fragment" means.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.